# text at the bottom of span

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<td>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="foo">
             Link Text
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

and I have

```
.foo
{
    height: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e8edff url('foo.png') top center no-repeat;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

and it renders something like this (with the background image)

```
 ________________
|    Link Text   |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
```

How can i make it so I renders like this?

```
 ________________
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|    Link Text   |
|________________|
```

The requirement is the every cell has to have a hyperlink and a background image and some text at the bottom.

Thanks

EDIT: here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yBKZS/) of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: if `height` is fixed, you can work with `line-height`

Comment: @yoda can you give me a brief example as to how I should use `line-height` to alight text at bottom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

give `vertical-align: bottom;`
 in `TD` instead of `span`

EDIT:
write like this

```
.foo
{
    height: 50px;
    background: #e8edff url('http://www.emblemmart.com/emblems-badges-insignias/media/logos/medium/BMW.gif') top center no-repeat;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;

}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/yBKZS/1/

Answer (score 4):

Put the `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `TD` not the `SPAN`.

`vertical-align` will not do what you want, except in two cases: On a table element, or on (or near) an image. See: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: That's because you are setting `.foo` to have a height of 90, and the table cell also has a height of 90. So even if `.foo` is at the bottom of the cell you won't be able to tell unless you make the table cell larger than the content. PS. `inline-block` does not work in all browsers, so avoid it. So basically: Remove `inline-block` and move the `height` to the table cell.

Comment: Thanks, I get something like this now http://jsfiddle.net/PeMnq/ with the changes you suggested. The only thing is the whole cell is not a link anymore.

Comment: Try adding `padding-top: 80px;` to .foo. It won't be exactly what you asked for, but it might be good enough. Not all of the cell will be a link, but most of it will. But if the text links are multiple lines in height the cells will get larger than specified.

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of the span to

```
margin-top: 'auto'
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to the `td` tag `<td valign="bottom">`

**UPDATE**

Here's what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/yBKZS/3/

**UPDATE 2**

If you don't need the image to be background you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yBKZS/8/

Comment: I see. I read this post http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html and got that idea.

Comment: better to go straight to the source :)

Comment: fyi, w3schools is source for nothing and they are not affiliated to w3c. see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I haven't heard of valign being depreciated. I'm using it on a regular basis. Did the fiddle work for you?

Comment: Thanks. The only thing missing is that the whole cell have to be linked, not just the text.